# How to count indicator per each group element?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a group and persons in each group. and an indicator. How to count indicator per each group for each person element?

```
     group  person   ind
       1       1      1
       1       1      1
       1       2      1
       2       1      0
       2       2      1
       2       2      1


     group       count

      1            2
      2            1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a dplyr solution might be helpful?

Edit: Based on comment, looks like you want the number of people with ind of 1 within each group?

```
dat <- data.frame("group" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  "person" = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2),
                  "ind" = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  distinct(group, person, ind) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(ind))
```

Or:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(person[ind==1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tapply()` for this:

```r
dat <- data.frame("group" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  "ind" = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))

tapply(dat$ind, dat$group, sum)
```

**Edit #1**
To be more illustrative for OP, consider group 1 as "A" and group 2 as "B"

```r
dat <- data.frame("group" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                  "ind" = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))

tapply(dat$ind, dat$group, sum)
```

You get the following result

```r
A B 
1 2
```

**Edit #2**
Given OP's revised problem, a base R solution using `tapply()`:

```r
tapply(dat$ind, list(dat$group, dat$person), sum)
```

Rows are group, columns are person:

```r
  1 2
1 2 1
2 0 2
```

Comment: Not if you ran the above code. The way to read the output of `tapply()` is that the first "row" (actually column names) are the group number and the second row (actually the first, since the first is actually column headers!) is the count of `ind` for each group.

Comment: Sorry , please see edit, I had missed something in the question

Comment: Just revised it for you

Comment: The output is not in a format that I want, I can't understand it. group is family and person is family's member indicator is if a person has driving licence or not! I want to know how many people  have driving licence in each family.